# App for gmail video chat

Tags: google-talk, video-conference, htc-incredible-s

I just bought HTC incredible S. It has front camera.
How can begin gmail video chat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is  now possible (May 2011):

Check out the [demonstration video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJAiH5-64sI&feature=player_embedded).

Note that this is available only for the `Nexus S` for now, but it should soon work for all *Android 2.3* devices.

Answer (score 5):

The service is [not available](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=100173) yet for Android devices:

> Voice and video in Gmail only works with the newer version of Gmail in supported browsers: FF 2.0+, IE 6.0+, Safari 3.0+, and Google Chrome.

However, it's likely they have something in the works. In the meantime, there are alternative services like [Fring](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fring) and [QiK](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qik.android).